# Select dropdown option redirecting on clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, css

I had created a sample drop down list, below is the code.

```
<select id="select-id">
<option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
<option value="">Amazon</option>
<option value="">Flipkart</option>
<option value="">Snapdeal</option>
 </select>
  <button>GO</button>
```

After selecting the dropdown item and clicking on GO button i want to redirect the page to respective sites like, https://www.amazon.in/ ,https://www.flipkart.com/ and https://www.snapdeal.com/ respectively.

Kindly help me how can i do this

Comment: You forgot to post the javascript you have now.

Comment: I'm going to ask first: what have you tried so far? Although the answer to this is quite simple and someone could make it in a few moments, generally people like to see the original asker has made some sort of effort to research and try it out for themselves. In fact especially as it's quite simple, then that is all the more reason to have done so. Is your free time more valuable than ours? Don't forget we are volunteers. See also http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I hope below code helps you,

```
<select id="select-id">
  <option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
  <option value="http://www.amazon.com">Amazon</option>
  <option value="http://www.flipkart.com">Flipkart</option>
  <option value="http://www.snapdeal.com">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
<button onclick="siteRedirect()">GO</button>

<script>
  function siteRedirect() {
    var selectbox = document.getElementById("select-id");
    var selectedValue = selectbox.options[selectbox.selectedIndex].value;
    window.location.href = selectedValue;
  }

</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following way:

```js
var linkArr = ["https://www.amazon.in/","https://www.flipkart.com/","https://www.snapdeal.com/"];
var selectedPosition = 0;
document.getElementById('select-id').addEventListener('change', function(){
  selectedPosition = this.selectedIndex;
});

document.getElementById('go').addEventListener('click', function(){
  if(selectedPosition != 0)
    window.location.href = linkArr[selectedPosition-1];
});
```

```html
<select id="select-id">
<option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
<option value="">Amazon</option>
<option value="">Flipkart</option>
<option value="">Snapdeal</option>
</select>
<button type="button" id="go">GO</button>
```

Comment: typo in `",https://www.flipkart.com/"`

Comment: @ADyson, thanks for the catch........fixed.

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="selectid">
    <option j-link="" value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
    <option j-link="http://amazon.com" value="">Amazon</option>
    <option j-link="http://flipkart.com" value="">Flipkart</option>
    <option j-link="http://snapdeal.com" value="">Snapdeal</option>
</select>

<button id="buttonid">GO</button>

<script>
    document.getElementById("buttonid").onclick = function () {
        var select = document.getElementById("selectid");
        var option = select.children[select.selectedIndex];

        if (!option || !option.getAttribute("j-link") || !option.getAttribute("j-link").length)
            return;

        window.location = option.getAttribute("j-link");
    };
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
// handle click 
$("#go").on("click", function(){
  //get selected option value
  var option =  $('#select-id').find('option:selected').attr('value');
  console.log(option)
   //redirect to that link
  var strWindowFeatures = "location=yes,height=570,width=520,scrollbars=yes,status=yes";
  var URL = option;
  var win = window.open(URL, "_blank", strWindowFeatures);
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="select-id" name="select-id">
<option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
<option value="https://www.amazon.in/">Amazon</option>
<option value="http://flipkart.com">Flipkart</option>
<option value="http://snapdeal.com">Snapdeal</option>
</select>

<button id="go">Go</button>
```

Comment: big assumption that OP is happy to use jQuery, or even (given how basic the question is) knows what it is, especially since you just posted code without any kind of explanation...

Comment: maybe a new programmer.

Comment: exactly...so my point is you should either provide an explanation for what you're doing and what OP will need to do in order to make the code work...or provide a solution without an 3rd party library

Answer (score 0):

if you are ok to use jquery :

```
<select id="select-id" name="select-id">
    <option value="" selected="">Pick a E-commerce</option>
    <option value="https://www.amazon.in/">Amazon</option>
    <option value="http://flipkart.com">Flipkart</option>
    <option value="http://snapdeal.com">Snapdeal</option>
</select>

<script>
$("#select-id").on("change", function(){
    location.href = this.value;
})
</script>
```

Comment: Same as another answer: big assumption that OP is happy to use jQuery, or even (given how basic the question is) knows what it is, especially since you just posted code without any kind of explanation...you should make it 100% clear what is required in order for this code to run